# Mock a property of an object to return a value that is coming from the object itself

Tags: c#, mocking, moq

I want to create a mock with an object returning for one property a value that comes from another property of the same mock instance, but I don't find how to setup this with Moq.

All signatures I find for Setup/SetupGet are allowing to return constant values only and not values coming from the same object.

Example :

```
void Main()
{
    var obj = GetMock().Object;

    obj.PropA = "test";

    Console.WriteLine(obj.Id); // Should return -354185609, as it's the result of "test".GetHashCode()

    obj.PropA = "test 2";

    Console.WriteLine(obj.Id); // Should return -1555281747, as it's the result of "test 2".GetHashCode()

}

public interface IMyObject
{
    int Id { get;set;}

    string PropA {get; set;}
}

public Mock<IMyObject> GetMock()
{
    var objectMock = new Mock<IMyObject>();

    objectMock.SetupAllProperties();

    objectMock
        .SetupGet((IMyObject s) => s.Id)
        //Here I would like to write something like : 
        .Returns(s => (a.PropA?.GetHashCode()).GetValueOrDefault()));
        // To have the Getter of Id initialized with the current value of PropA.GetHashCode()

    return objectMock;
}
```

Thanks for your proposals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Callback` to store values from `set` and then reuse it within the `Returns`. Something like this:

```
string propA = null;

var mock = new Mock<IMyObject>();
mock.SetupSet(m => m.PropA = It.IsAny<string>())
    .Callback<string>(s => propA = s);
mock.Setup(m => m.Id)
    .Returns(() => (propA?.GetHashCode()).GetValueOrDefault());

mock.Object.PropA = "test";

Assert.Equal("test".GetHashCode(), mock.Object.Id);

mock.Object.PropA = "test 2";

Assert.Equal("test 2".GetHashCode(), mock.Object.Id);
```

---

The other option is to have actuall implementation and use `CallBase` feature. (Similar as the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55954596/3311799))

```
public abstract class MyObjectDummy : IMyObject
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }  
    public virtual string PropA { get; set; }
}

var mock = new Mock<MyObjectDummy>();
mock.SetupSet(m => m.PropA = It.IsAny<string>()).CallBase();
mock.SetupGet(m => m.PropA).CallBase();
mock.Setup(m => m.Id).Returns(() => (mock.Object.PropA?.GetHashCode()).GetValueOrDefault());

mock.Object.PropA = "test";
Assert.Equal("test".GetHashCode(), mock.Object.Id);
```

Comment: Thanks it works! However as I also need to actually assign "PropA" setter with the value supplied, I have just updated to reassign it : settingDefinitionMock.SetupGet(m => m.SettingKey).Returns(() => settingKey); Thank you.

Comment: Just for completeness, is there some kind of syntax looking like my example in first post to directly access the mock instance in its configuration and access a property (or method) implemented inside, or are we constrained to use syntax with external variable captured by predicate which is not very straightforward to read ?

Comment: @AFract you could maybe use `CallBase` functionality but then you need to have real implementation, with interfaces this is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes Moq setup gets very difficult to read, often to the point where it's hard for someone else to tell what is being tested. In those scenarios we can often "mock" using a test double - that is, a class that implements the interface.

Here's an example. I can't say for sure if this does what you're trying to do with your mock, but that's really the point. It's not easy to read that setup and tell what it does. On the other hand, it's really easy to tell what this does:

```
public class ObjectWhereIdReturnsPropAHashCode : IMyObject
{
    public int Id
    {
        get => PropA?.GetHashCode() ?? 0;
        set => Id = value;
    }

    public string PropA { get; set; }
}
```

...and it was much easier to create then a `Mock<IObject>` that does the same thing.

When you create an instance of the test double, the name of the class can clearly indicate what that test double does for the purpose of that particular test. (To be fair, you can also do that with Moq by making a well-named function that creates and returns the mock.)

It's also an easier pattern to follow for the next developer who must either create a new test double or modify the existing one.

I'm not suggesting that we shouldn't use Moq - I use it all the time - just that we should look at alternatives whenever it starts to get unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: Hello. Honestly the problem I encounter in first post is much simple to solve with truly implemented class than a dynamic mock exactly like you illustrated and I was aware of that, but I was very interested to discover how to handle this kind of scenario with Moq. And the sample in first post does not cover all the needs I have for my mock.

Comment: It's funny because I like to know how stuff works, but I've been in projects where the mocks get out of control - it sets up one mock to do some complicated stuff and then sets up another mock that returns the first mock. Granted, some of that is an effect of other code issues. But when it gets to that point my eyes glaze over and I just can't tell what's going on anymore.

Comment: I am agree to not overuse complex mocks, however it remains interesting to know how to handle some particular cases :). I found mine interesting and I was not able to solve it with a convenient syntax with Moq.